# DB2 Export-Import Error

Tags: sql, database, import, db2, export

I have a db2 database in my first vm computer. I want to import some tables from it. When i export one of these tables from first vm as .ixf file everything will perfect and i can export it. But when i tried to import from new table on the second vm i got that kind of problem and my query for this :

```
CONNECT TO RS;
IMPORT FROM "C:\rs_cust.ixf" OF IXF MESSAGES "a.txt" CREATE INTO RS.RS_CUSTOMERS;
CONNECT RESET;
```

[image: db2 error]
So how can i solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to force the table creation, as it is explained in the reason code.

> For reason codes 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 14, 17, and 18:
>
> To force the import utility to create the tables despite the fact that some information is missing, specify the FORCECREATE parameter when you issue the IMPORT command with the CREATE or REPLACE_CREATE parameter.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008304.html : Table 5. Valid file type modifiers for the import utility: IXF file format

It was added in db2 V9.1: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.rn.doc/doc/c0023922.htm